# make Wordpress 2017 menu fixed

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I thought it would be pretty easy, but it's making me mad :/

I *just* want my twenty seventeen main nav to be `fixed` in the top right corner of the page.

what i did so far is straightforward:

```
.navigation-top {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  top:0;
  right:0;

  .wrap {
    margin-right: 0;
    position: fixed!important;
    right: 0;

    #top-menu {
      text-align: right;
    }
  }
}
```

Menu is where i want it to be, no problem.
but there is a white gap i can't get rid of.
Or should is say, i **can** get rid of:

```
.custom-header {
  margin-bottom: 0!important;
}
```

but (of course) this gets overridden inline when resizing. there seems to be nothing i can do about it, the white gap even **grows** when i resize the window (as far as i've learned there is a js function that re-calculates the height of that white gap depending on something i have apparently broken by placing the menu in the corner..)

What is the cleanest way to do this?
I just want the Menu fixed in the upper corner and the white gap gone (while still having the hamburger menu appear, of course)

Comment: I wonder if you ever figured it out? I think I"m seeing that same gap. I eventually made the .custom-header { height:0; }. But now my .navigation-top is being given a JS-enabled class="navigation-top  site-navigation-fixed" immediately on page load, which is overlapping my site branding.

Comment: hey there. it's been a while, so i'm not quite sure on the spot. but i THINK i did it like this: removed the factory nav completely, then added a custom sidebar/menu (with some plugin) and then fixed THAT to the top right corner. IIRC that worked much better. if you want, i can have a look and try to figure it out one of these days, but i think thats the direction i went